# How can I add simple String value to JsonObjectBuilder?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jsonb, java-ee-8

This is a follow-up question from [Java JsonObjectBuilder adding extra 'metadata' when added as child to JsonObjectBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35191003/330457).

When I [add](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html#add-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) a `String`, I see

```
"href":{
    "chars":"http://test.com/test/1",
    "string":"http://test.com/test/1",
    "valueType":"STRING"
}
```

What I expected is

```
"href": "http://..."
```

When I [add](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html#add-java.lang.String-int-) a number, I see

```
"a":{
    "integral":true,
    "valueType":"NUMBER"
}
```

I expect something like

```
"a": 1
```

What did I do wrong?

This is my code.

```
@Override
public JsonObject adaptToJson(final Link original) throws Exception {
    return ofNullable(original).map(v -> {
        final JsonObjectBuilder builder = createObjectBuilder();
        //builder.add("a", 1);
        //builder.add("b", 1L);
        ofNullable(v.getUri()).map(URI::toString).ifPresent(href -> builder.add("href", JsonbBuilder.create().toJson(href, String.class)));
        ofNullable(v.getRel()).ifPresent(rel -> builder.add("rel", rel));
        ofNullable(v.getTitle()).ifPresent(title -> builder.add("title", title));
        return builder.build();
    }).orElse(null);
}
```

And I'm using `johnzon-jsonb`. `yasson` seems have a problem.

Comment: Where does `DateUtils.getIsoString` come from?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The linked question is not my own.

Comment: Well how about showing your code?

Comment: @ScaryWombat As you wish.